# pass variable in as parameter to user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a user control on my page and I'm looking to pass a variable to a property in a user control. I'm only getting the variable value coming through as "<%=mOrderId%>"  = rather than the actual value of the variable, e.g. 5, 7, 9.

E.g. User control on page with Order ID passed through

```
<uc1:DocTemplate runat="server" ID="docTemplate" OrderID="<%=mOrderId %>"/>
```

when I get the variable in the code behind I just get "<%=mOrderId %>" ?

What do I need to do to pass the value through?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it will not work unless you databind your attributes.

Call this after instantiating the control...

```
DocTemplate.DataBind()
```